# Ember data: side-loading hasMany relationship using a non-id field

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

I was wondering if you can side-load a hasMany relationship in ember-data - hooked on a non-id column. Here are my code snippets-

```
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr(),
    lastName: DS.attr(),
    photo: DS.hasMany('photo', {async:true})
});

App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
    path: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    owner: DS.belongsTo('user', {async:true}),
});


App.ProfileSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    attrs:{
        photo: {embedded: 'load'}
    },
});
```

The JSON returned by localhost:/api/profiles/ is:

```
[
    {
        "photos": [
            "media/pic3.jpeg", 
            "media/pic4.jpeg"
        ], 
        "id": "5441b6b2bc8ae304d4e6c10e", 
        "first_name": "Dave", 
        "last_name": "Gordon", 
        "profile_pic": "media/profilePic.jpg", 
        "member_since": "2014-01-03T00:00:00", 
        "membership": "Silver", 
        "theme_pic": "media/profilePic.jpg"
    }
]
```

As we see here, I am trying to hook up photos using 'path' field of `photo` instead of `id` of photos. I can't seem to get ember to send an async call. Is it possible to tell ember to make an async call based off of an non-id field. I feel there should be a way coz I intend to send an async call based off of a custom generated key. ANy help is greatly appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think of that as an association, but rather just another property with a type of array.

You should be able to just change your model like this:

```
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr(),
    lastName: DS.attr(),
    photos: DS.attr()
});
```

Then you should be able to access the property as an array (possible object) in your template.

If necessary, you might need to create a custom transform like this:

```
App.ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize:function(value) {
       return value;
    }
});
```

Then you can do:

```
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr(),
    lastName: DS.attr(),
    photos: DS.attr('array')
});
```

Comment: This way I think would work for embedded fields, i.e., {embedded: 'always'}. But, would it work for {embedded:'load'}? Each profile has a set of photos associated with it. This way, I thought would not do async call. Moreover, how would ember know to fetch the photos only pertaining to that particular profile? Thank you